# Does anyone know where I can find a list of geodetic benchmark locations for all of Canada?

Tags: geospatial, canada

Does anyone know where I can find a list of geodetic benchmark locations for all of Canada?

I am looking for a few specific control monuments in Arctic Canada with accurate coordinates

Comment: Since it looks like you found an answer (based on your comments in the [identical question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/333360/81764) on [GIS.se]), would you mind posting an answer here? This is a good question, and I think the answer would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here using a survey plan search: http://clss.nrcan.gc.ca/clss/plan/search-recherche